Creating CSR from an existing certificate - Copy everything except the Organization Name value
I have an existing certificate that will be expiring soon.
And now I want to create a new CSR and send it to the CA.
And I am using the following openssl command.
openssl x509 -x509toreq -copy_extensions copyall -in mycert.cer -signkey mycert.key -out mycert.csr

This works fine, but here one thing changed since the last certificate, which is the "Organization Name". Earlier it was ABC and now it is XYZ
Is it possible to copy everything from the existing certificate except the "Organization Name" and add it manually?
